# Get ParallelStream().parallel() data in sequence

Tags: spring, spring-boot, collections, parallel-processing

I have a situation where i need to call the ParallelStream().parallel() on my data and get the response in sequence.
Here is the code snippet:

```
  transactions.getContent().parallelStream().parallel().forEach((transaction) -> {
                //write data to a file.
            });
```

This transaction data is sorted using createDate field.
Once, the file is written in file the date column is not sorted.
I want to run this task in parallel as per my code(performance) and get the final output in sequence. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: The stream returned by `.parallelStream()` is already parallel. There’s no point in calling `parallel()` again. You can perform the final action in order using `forEachOrdered`, but since there are no other operations in your example, there will be no benefit in using `parallelStream()` when the stream’s only operation needs to be performed sequentially.

Comment: Thanks for this information @Holger